# On change of content div, do an action

Tags: jquery, drag-and-drop

I have a drag and drop system going on and I want to execute a action when something is dropped into a different container. So I guess it has two possibility, one is executing the jQuery action after the drop is finished, the other is to react to a change in the div containing the drag able items.

This is the action I want to execute after a drag has been performed (it's a click function now)

```
eventie.bind(button, 'click', function() {
  msnry = new Masonry( container );
});
```

This is the drag drop code.

```
// Drag drop function.

(function ($) {
var lastPlace;

$(".painting").draggable({
    revert: true,
    zIndex: 10,
    snap: ".vote",
    snapMode: "inner",
    snapTolerance: 40,
    start: function (event, ui) {
        lastPlace = $(this).parent();
    }
});

$(".vote").droppable({
    drop: function (event, ui) {
        var dropped = ui.draggable;
        var droppedOn = this;

        if ($(droppedOn).children().length > 0) {
            $(droppedOn).children().detach().prependTo($(lastPlace));
        }

        $(dropped).detach().css({
            top: 0,
            left: 0
        }).prependTo($(droppedOn));
    }
});
})(jQuery);
```

When you drag/drop a painting into a container in the top it creates a gap. Then you have to click the container with the paintings to refit that gap. I want it to happen after the drag/drop function is finished.
http://codepen.io/alucardu/pen/qubzx

Answer (score 0):

After some researching I found http://jqueryui.com/droppable/ which shows this code

```
$( "#droppable" ).droppable({
  drop: function( event, ui ) {
    $( this )
      .addClass( "ui-state-highlight" )
      .find( "p" )
        .html( "Dropped!" );
  }
});
```

I edited to this:

```
$( ".vote" ).droppable({
    drop: function( event, ui ) {
      var dropped = ui.draggable;
      var droppedOn = this;

      if ($(droppedOn).children().length > 0) {
          $(droppedOn).children().detach().prependTo($(lastPlace));
      }

      $(dropped).detach().css({
          top: 0,
          left: 0
      }).prependTo($(droppedOn));
      msnry = new Masonry( container );
    }
  });
```

It now executes the `msnry = new Masonry( container );` code after the `.vote` has been dropped.